# How to Lock the data in a cell in excel using vba

Tags: vba, excel

I want to stop others from editing the cell contents in my excel sheet using VBA. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17111648/how-to-lock-excel-cells-in-vba/18868676#18868676

Answer (score 32):

You can first choose which cells you don't want to be protected (to be user-editable) by setting the Locked status of them to False:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:C3").Locked = False
```

Then, you can protect the sheet, and all the other cells will be protected.
The code to do this, and still allow your VBA code to modify the cells is:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Protect UserInterfaceOnly:=True
```

or

```
Call Worksheets("Sheet1").Protect(UserInterfaceOnly:=True)
```

Comment: You may also want to add a password, otherwise it's a trivial matter to just click "unprotect worksheet" and then you can make edits to the previously locked cells.

Comment: the line above Worksheets("Sheet1").Protect(UserInterfaceOnly:=True) should be Worksheets("Sheet1").Protect UserInterfaceOnly:=True , i.e. no parentheses

Comment: @dinotom, look at the edit history and the guy who edited it that way explains why

Comment: @Lance Roberts... ok, I don;t know how to see the edit history but that syntax doesnt work

Comment: Yeh, an oddity of VBA. You can use the parentheses if you use "Call". I'll edit.

Answer (score 4):

Try using the `Worksheet.Protect` method, like so:

```
Sub ProtectActiveSheet()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    ws.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, _
        Scenarios:=True, Password="SamplePassword"
End Sub
```

You should, however, be concerned about including the password in your VBA code.  You don't necessarily need a password if you're only trying to put up a simple barrier that keeps a user from making small mistakes like deleting formulas, etc.

Also, if you want to see how to do certain things in VBA in Excel, try recording a Macro and looking at the code it generates.  That's a good way to get started in VBA.

Answer (score 3):

Let's say for example in one case, if you want to locked cells from range A1 to I50 then below is the code:

```
Worksheets("Enter your sheet name").Range("A1:I50").Locked = True
ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="Enter your Password"
```

In another case if you already have a protected sheet then follow below code:

```
ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="Enter your Password"
Worksheets("Enter your sheet name").Range("A1:I50").Locked = True
ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="Enter your Password"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also do it on the worksheet level captured in the worksheet's change event.  If that suites your needs better.  Allows for dynamic locking based on values, criteria, ect...

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    'set your criteria here
    If Target.Column = 1 Then

        'must disable events if you change the sheet as it will
        'continually trigger the change event
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Application.Undo
        Application.EnableEvents = True

        MsgBox "You cannot do that!"
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub LockCells()

Range("A1:A1").Select

Selection.Locked = True

Selection.FormulaHidden = False

ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=False, Contents:=True, Scenarios:= False, AllowFormattingCells:=True, AllowFormattingColumns:=True, AllowFormattingRows:=True, AllowInsertingColumns:=True, AllowInsertingRows:=True, AllowInsertingHyperlinks:=True, AllowDeletingColumns:=True, AllowDeletingRows:=True, AllowSorting:=True, AllowFiltering:=True, AllowUsingPivotTables:=True

End Sub
```