# Deselect Subrange

Tags: vba

I want to lock the range `A4:B9` in my sheet. Now as it [looks like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3037400/how-to-lock-the-data-in-a-cell-in-excel-using-vba) the only way to accomplish that is to set the `Lock=false` status to all cells I do not want to be locked and then protect the whole file.

My problem is, that I have just a little range that has to be protected, so I need to find a way to create a range with all cells but e.g. `A4:B9`. I know intersect and union but cannot come up with an idea to apply them to get my goal accomplished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote this that works for me:

```
Sub deselect_subranges()
Dim cell As Range
Dim rngAll As Range
Dim rngMy As Range
Dim rngNew As Range

Set rngAll = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1:AZ400")
Set rngMy = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("C3:E8")

Set rngNew = Nothing

For Each cell In rngAll
    If Intersect(cell, rngMy) Is Nothing Then
        If rngNew Is Nothing Then
            Set rngNew = cell
        Else
            Set rngNew = Union(rngNew, cell)
        End If
    End If
Next cell

rngNew.Select

End Sub
```