# Freeze column content from drop down in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, validation

Hi I am new to excel for this kinds requirements.

I want to freeze the cell content (from a drop down) once a selection is made. Users should not be able to modify the entered content. Once the selection is made from data validation list then user can not change it. 
Ex. If we have "M" and "F" in drop down(Data validation). Once user select "M" then he will not allow to change this with other option.

Let me know if you need more clarification. Direct me to the answer if question is already there.

Comment: This question have been already resolved: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3037400/how-to-lock-the-data-in-a-cell-in-excel-using-vba

Comment: I think I need to rephrase it correctly. First user has to make his choice(M or F). Once he select if then it will get freeze and he will not have choice to  change his first selection.

Comment: you can add the code from the link I gave it to you, but in order to work you need to to paste the code not in a module but in the sheet code editor (and then you need to select in the first dropdownlist option "Worksheet"and from the second one option "Change"). After you select those option you paste the code and modify the code(use "Target.Cells"). that should lock evrey cell after you chose your option

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest having conditionals control your validation. For instance:

If your validated list containing 'M' & 'F' is in cell A1, place a condition in say cell A2:

```
=IF(OR(A1="M",A1="F"),A1,"M")
```

And then for A3:

```
=IF(A2=A1,A2,"F")
```

Then set your validation list to cells A2:A3. By doing this, the dropdown can start unpopulated, a user makes a selection, and then the cells guiding the validation change to the users selection. This is a decent option if you are not comfortable with VBA. Good luck!